# Render to Tex only partially writing

Tags: opengl

*I apologise for the limited code in this question, but It's tied into a [personal project](https://github.com/Robadob/sdl_exp/tree/nav_gen) with much OpenGL functionality abstracted behind classes. Hoping someone visually recognises the problem and can offer direction.*

During the first execution of my animation loop, I'm creating a `GL_R32F` (format: `GL_RED`, type: `GL_FLOAT`) texture, rendering an orthographic projection of a utah teapot to it (for the purposes of debugging this I'm writing the same float to every fragment).

The texture however renders incorrectly, as it should be a solid silhouette.

[image]

Re-running the the program causes the patches to move around.

[image]

I've spent a good few hours tweaking things trying to work out the cause, I've compared the code to my working shadow mapping example which similarly writes to a  `GL_R32F` texture, yet I can't find a cause.

I've narrowed it down, to find that it's only the first renderpass to the texture which this occurs. This wouldn't be so much of an issue except I don't require more than a single render (and looping the bindFB, setViewport, render, unbindFB doesn't fix it).

I've

If anyone has an suggestions for specific code extracts to provide, I'll try and edit the question.

Comment: Pease include all the relevant code **in the question itself**.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it's unlikely to help potential future visitors. It's a very specific bug in a very specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a rogue call to `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` during an earlier stage of the algorithm.

This makes sense because I was writing to a single channel, therefore the Alpha channel would contain random garbage, leading to garbled texture.